# Offline services in mapbox react native

Tags: react-native, offline, react-native-mapbox-gl

Is mapbox library in react native can do some offline services for routing or navigation in react native or not?
Please Help me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue at the moment too. So far I have learned that, yes React Native supports Mapbox (although tricky to set up)

I am unsure about Navigation but it does offline manager for static maps and mapbox studio projects.

https://github.com/nitaliano/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/docs/OfflineManager.md